# Mapping to a polymorphic list

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to ElasticSearch and trying to use it on my C# application with Nest. I have a class which holds a list of a base type with classes which inherit from it:

```cs
public class Automobile
{
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public double EngineSize { get; set; }
}

public class Truck : Automobile
{
    public double CarryWeight { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Automobile
{
    public short SaftyStars { get; set; }
}

public class MotorCycle : Automobile
{
    public double DecibleNoise { get; set; }
}

public class AutoDealerShip
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.nested)]
    public IList<Automobile> Models { get; set; }

    public AutoDealerShip()
    {
        Models = new List<Automobile>();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to map the class so that the actual objects would be saved:

```cs
ElasticClient.MapFluent<AutoDealerShip>(m => m.MapFromAttributes().
                                             Properties(prop => prop.
                                             NestedObject<Automobile>(n => n.
                                                 Name(p => p.
                                                 Models.First()).
                                                      MapFromAttributes().
                                                      Dynamic())));
```

When trying to index data and retrieve it:

```cs
private static void IndexPolymorphicObject()
{
    ElasticClient.DeleteIndex(PersonIndex);

    var dealerShip = new AutoDealerShip();
    dealerShip.Name = "Mikes dealership";
    dealerShip.Models.Add(new Truck());
    dealerShip.Models.Add(new Car());
    dealerShip.Models.Add(new MotorCycle());
    ElasticClient.Index(dealerShip);
    ElasticClient.Flush();
}

private static void GetPolyMorphicData()
{
    var result = ElasticClient.Search<AutoDealerShip>(srch => srch.
                                               Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
    var dealerShip = result.Documents.First();
    foreach (var automobile in dealerShip.Models)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Automobile of type {0}",automobile.GetType());
    }
}
```

I keep getting back objects of type *AutoMobile*. Is there a way to store polymorphic data using nest?

Thanks,

Izhar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEST by default has great support for contravariant results of the documents you store

So if you do

`Index<B>()`

`Index<C>()`

`Index<D>()`

And then do a search for `Search<A>(s=>s.Types(B,C,D))` given that all of them derive from A you will get an IEnumerable result with actual instances of B, C and D inside of it.

To get contra/covariance going inside your own document you'll have to do the wiring yourself.

You will have to register a custom jsonconverter on the property to make sure JSON.net deserializes the json back to the actual subtype instead of the supper.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This might be a stupid question, but how do these are sub objects. How do I index them?

Comment: That's what i tried to explain, as this is covariance inside your own object you have to write your own serializer to handle the covariance on the property by writing a custom Json.net converter for it.

Comment: @MartijnLaarman Is there some sort of magic required to get the top level document polymorphism to work like you described? I'm doing exactly the use case you mentioned and I'm getting deserialization errors because its trying to instantiate my abstract base class instead of the type I actually stored. I don't want to hijack this thread so I created this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1682